# Why is this method literally delete bookmark range? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, bookmarks

I work in C# on a program and one peace of the program need to replace some bookmark text, but only the text and  the bookmark range need to be the same as the text length what i inserted.

I searched about that but i'm stuck with this method:

```
internal void BookMarkReplaceNative(Document doc,
                Bookmark bookmark,
                string newText)
        {
            object rng = bookmark.Range;
            string bookmarkName = bookmark.Name;

            bookmark.Range.Text = newText;

            doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, ref rng);
        }
```

With one example (CONTR_L is a string) :

```
Bookmark NR_CONTR =doc.Bookmarks.get_Item("NR_CONTR");
BookMarkReplaceNative(doc,NR_CONTR, CONTR_L);
```

The problem is that once the program replace the text the range is just the begining of the text, before the first letter.

Whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, I can use the following code to replace bookmark text successfully.

```
        using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
        Word.Application application = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document document = application.Documents.Open("D:\\1.docx");
        application.Visible = true;
        document.Bookmarks["First"].Select();
        application.Selection.TypeText("Firstbook");
        document.Save();
        application.Quit();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes its replace the bookmark, the code i use replace the bookmark too but i need to replace a way that the selected bookmark remain. Like in your code the bookmark "First" remain on the "Firstbook". 
                                      
Like before the replace the bookmark name : "First" and the value (selction) "888888"
and after the replace rhe bookmark name is  : "First" and the vlaue is "Firstbook"

Comment: @Csabatron99, after reading your comment, I still can not understand 'Like in your code the bookmark "First" remain on the "Firstbook".' Can you give a detailed description? Or you can tell me what you want to get after execute the replace code.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english somtimes i cannot explain what i want properly xd. I added 2 photo to the next answer to explain things.

Answer (score 0):

[Bookmark original.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM8CJ.png)

So here is my bookmarking, you see here the selection or what its called for the bookmark is the "NR_CONTRACT_PRELUNGIRE" and the program swaps that right?

So when i swap it it becomes like this for example

[Bookmark swapped.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN3Bq.png)

But the range or the selection for the bookmark is lost, its not the "7" just the flashing cursor before the "7".

But i want(for example) the selection or the range of the bookmark is to be the "7"

Comment: I want to know your replaced text is 7 or 7/11.08.2020. Also, can you give me a picture about what you want to get in the final?

Comment: just the 7 because the date is another bookamr all of the bookmark is changed from a form field this is one of them https://imgur.com/by0rpCy . And this is like what i want in the end: https://imgur.com/uSsMCIg    /     https://imgur.com/cThh95j .

Comment: The bookmark need to remain that way i mentioned the previous comment because later there is a possybility that the program need to extract the bookmark information

Comment: So, @JackJJun-MSFT did you manage to find something ?